# Is possible to change the positions of the tabs in vim?

Tags: vim

I was wondering if is there any way to change the place of the tabs. Anyone can help me about this? I would like to have vim as my favourite ide..:)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out `help :tabm[ove]`. Essentially you could do:

`:tabm +N` to move current tab N places to the right. Or `:tabm -N` to move N places left.

Answer (score 2):

Vim is not an IDE, it's an editor. You won't turn it into an IDE, no matter how hard you try.

Anyway, read `:h tabmove`:

```
:tabmove 0
```

moves the current tab to the first position

```
:tabmove 2
```

moves the current tab to after the 2 tab

```
:tabmove
```

moves the current tab to the last position

Answer (score 0):

What do you exactly mean by "place of the tabs"? The other answers have already shown how to move individual tab pages around.

If you're inquiring about where Vim places the tab labels, that cannot be changed; they will always be between the GUI menu and the windows. In GVIM, you can only "downgrade" the tab appearance from graphical to textual via

```
:set guioptions-=e
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Split Manipulation

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>, <kbd>R</kbd> (Swap top/bottom or left/right split)
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>, <kbd>T</kbd> (Break out current window into a new tabview)
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>, <kbd>o</kbd> (Close every window in the current tabview but the current one)

Answer (score 0):

When using the tabline (with guioptions-=e), you can drag and drop tabs with your mouse.

There is a patch pending (but not applied yet as of Vim 7.4.1054) to expand this to the GUI tabs as well:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/vim_dev/LnZVZYls1yk/fj_Gz0vhnrsJ